# Scheduler version

Tags: pallet-scheduler

I have added a Scheduler into my pallet, I'm following referenda pallet as model.

I have written some tests, and the scheduler functionality is working.

However, I have noticed that in my unit tests the compiler is asking for a `v2` interface while in the pallet is asking for a `v3` interface.

I can't see why is this happening, In my Pallet:

```rust
use frame_support::{
    traits::{
        schedule::{
            v3::{Anon as ScheduleAnon, Named as ScheduleNamed},
        },

...

#[pallet::config]
pub trait Config: frame_system::Config {

...

        type Scheduler: ScheduleAnon<BlockNumberFor<Self>, CallOf<Self>, PalletsOriginOf<Self>>
        + ScheduleNamed<BlockNumberFor<Self>, CallOf<Self>, PalletsOriginOf<Self>>;

...

}
```

Any idea what could be triggering this?

Comment: What kind of test is that and where does it come from? Why is the test not updated to require a v3 interface?

Answer (score 1):

After creating utility functions in the pallet for handling scheduling the issue went away.

I was trying to use Scheduler without preimages pallet because I only plan to schedule inline calls, but I had to add it anyway. I think this could be the root of the problem.